# Now is the time to stamp out unanswerable questions

Tags: discussion

[How do you recognize when you are playing "on tilt"?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-do-you-recognize-when-you-are-playing-on-tilt)

this question is analogous to

- "what is good to drink while programming?"
- "How do I know when my computer is exploding?"

or more generically,

- "What is the best way to accomplish X?"
- "What is your favorite way to do Y?"

If this site is going to work on the stackexchange model, I think it's important to keep the questions definitively answerable.

Comment: Specifically about your first example, I moderately disagree. Recognizing "Tilt" is a psychological question which is certainly a skillful addition to anyone's game. Admittedly, this specific question is incredibly broad but the premise of discussing strategies to reduce tilts effects are valuable. Very, very, veeeery basically, it comes down to applying a consistent thought process, even if that process is wrong. But thats for another thread. :)

Comment: I understand your point of view, but this question will have a different answer for each person. A series of anecdotes, while interesting, I don't think really belongs here. I could be wrong though.

Comment: For future reference, if you start a meta discussion based upon a specific question (or if you cast a close vote, particularly during private beta), it is important to link to your meta discussion or explain your reasoning for the close vote in the question, otherwise the discussion does not get the visibility this site needs.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree (obviously, as the OP of the other question), particularly with your analogies.

Playing on tilt is a pretty serious problem for many players, even experienced veterans.  It also has consequences on betting that are pretty specific to poker.

There's a big difference between "what is a good strategy for handling a relatively common situation that can cause serious problems for my play" and "what's a good snack while [insert activity here]".

I don't believe the question is phrased to solicit personal anecdotes.  So far the answers have given some pretty concrete tips, several of which are exclusively relevant to poker.

At worst, if there question results in far too many answers, each offering a few useful tips, they can be consolidated into a Community Wiki.  While not a favorite format, this is what Community Wiki was intended to accomplish: create single resources to consolidate large volumes of useful and relevant suggestions into a comprehensive guide that addresses something that is likely to be of use to many visitors.

Answer (score 1):

This particular question is addressed widely in poker books. As such, it is eminently "answerable" by reference to these books or writers, to the standards of the site.